# node-ldapauth ReferenceError: err is not defined at

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to prototype LDAP Authentication on an intranet application we are developing and here is some sample code I've written to demonstrate if it'll work. However, I'm getting errors and I'm unable to find a solution to them anywhere online.

Here is the full error I get:

```
ReferenceError: err is not defined at /Users/tdeshpande/Dropbox/NodeAuth/app.js:32:54 at 
Object.handle (/Users/tdeshpande/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware
/basicAuth.js:89:7) at next (/Users/tdeshpande/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect
/lib/proto.js:193:15) at Object.expressInit [as handle] (/Users/tdeshpande/node_modules
/express/lib/middleware.js:30:5) at next (/Users/tdeshpande/node_modules/express
/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:193:15) at Object.query [as handle] (/Users/tdeshpande
/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/query.js:45:5) at next (/Users
/tdeshpande/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:193:15) at 
Function.app.handle (/Users/tdeshpande/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect
/lib/proto.js:201:3) at Server.app (/Users/tdeshpande/node_modules/express/node_modules
/connect/lib/connect.js:65:37) at Server.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
```

And here is my code

```
var connect = require('connect');
var LdapAuth = require('ldapauth');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// Config from a .json or .ini file or whatever.
var config = {

    url: 'ldap://intranetldapserver:389',
    adminDn: 'userName',
    adminPassword: 'secret',
    searchBase: 'dc=corp,dc=company,dc=com, ou=People',
    searchFilter: '(&(objectcategory=person)(samaccountname=*))',
    searchAttributes: ['samaccountname']

};

var ldap = new LdapAuth(config);

var LdapAuthfunc = function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("LDAP Auth error: %s", err);
        callback(err);
    } 
    else {
        callback(err, user);
    }
}

//Authenticator
app.use(express.basicAuth(function (username, password, callback) {
  ldap.authenticate(username, password, LdapAuthfunc(err, user));
  }));


// Basic Authenticator
// app.use(express.basicAuth('testUser', 'testPassword'));



app.get('/', function(req, res) {
 res.send('Test Completed');
});

app.listen(8080);
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.use(express.basicAuth(function (username, password, callback) {
  ldap.authenticate(username, password, LdapAuthfunc(err, user));
}));
```

Do you see an `err` in scope? (Or a `user` for that matter?)

I think you might just want:

```
ldap.authenticate(username, password, LdapAuthfunc);
```

Then, after that, `callback` isn’t in scope. You might want to bind that or something:

```
function ldapAuth(callback, err, user) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("LDAP Auth error: %s", err);
        callback(err);
    } 
    else {
        callback(err, user);
    }
}

// Authenticator
app.use(express.basicAuth(function (username, password, callback) {
    ldap.authenticate(username, password, ldapAuth.bind(null, callback));
}));
```

Pick up [jsHint](https://npmjs.org/package/jshint)!

<sub>P.S. PascalCase for constructors only, please.</sub>

Comment: I don't. How should I handle login failure then?

Comment: Also, I'm using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20525070/why-is-node-ldapauth-so-slow-even-when-cached as one of the references for writing this prototype.

Comment: Thanks! Solved the node.js issue!